# How do I fix this (blue) screen issue when I connect my MacBook Pro with my Monitor?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

Now, the issue is only coming when I connect my MacBook, the monitor is working fine when I connect a Windows laptop to it. Any thoughts on how to fix this issue, I tried changing the display settings in the Preferences but couldn't fix it, tried scaling to different resolutions but didn't help.

Model: MacBook Pro 2018 13 inch

OS: Catalina

Monitor: HP VH240a

Type: HDMI

The monitor was working absolutely fine till now, but suddenly started behaving like this with the MacBook.

[image: A blue screen when I connect MacBook Pro to an external monitor]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I know it can be frustrating when you're attempting to solve an issue, however it's vital that you provide us with sufficient details to assist you. As the question is written, we don't have all the info we need. For example, telling us *"I tried changing some settings in the Preferences"* doesn't actually tell us much. Can you edit your question to clarify exactly what you've tried so far? Please also include the model of MBP and display, as well as the version of macOS you're running. Also, has this display ever worked ok with the MBP, or is this a new setup?